# Perl framework for html

Tags: perl

I want to authorise a team dedicatedly for password reset/printer queue delete kind of L1 tasks. I have planned to do so via 1 menu using Perl script. And I want it to be front end at HTML. I don't want user to login in server's black screen. They just login into web portal-> see the menu-> select an item-> do the task->exit.

Now, I am thinking what framework I can use to achieve this. 
How user password would be transferred securely from web portal to my server?
How are you going to encrypt/secure the web communication?
How are you going to encrypt/secure passwords?
Even if you use one of the built-in methods for encrypting the passwords at authentication time, how will you secure passwords in user input for something like a password reset function?

I really need your valuable suggestions on this.

thanks,
Prashant

Comment: Your questions are more so general web development than Perl specific. Here you go, list of Web frameworks written in Perl: https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/web_frameworks

Comment: Well, you can say it is web based system administration interface.

Answer (score 4):

See this cool framework **Mojolicious**, it's really up to date, plus author update it frequently.

[Official mojolicious site](http://mojolicio.us/)